# Hive SQL Ranking With Ties

Tags: sql, oracle, hive, hiveql, ranking-functions

**How to Re-Write below Query in Hive SQL**
I have tried the below in Oracle SQL and it works but need to write the same in Hive QL

```
select * from sales order by unit_price fetch with ties
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's ORDER BY .. FETCH NEXT N ROWS WITH TIRES is used to limit the number of top N (ORDER BY is used) rows returned to the number specified by NEXT (FIRST). And with tires means that if some rows have the same order by value, they also will be returned in addition to the number of rows specified.

Hive does not have FETCH functionality. There is LIMIT, which does not support WITH TIRES.

You can achieve similar functionality using analytics dense_rank() function plus WHERE filter. For example we need to fetch 5 sales with lowest price and if there are sales with the same price, also return them. dense_rank will assign the same rank to the rows with the same price.

```
select * 
from
(
    select s.*, 
           dense_rank() over(order by unit_price) rnk --lowest unit_price first
                                                      --to get highest price, use order by unit_price DESC
     from sales s 
) 
where rnk<=5  --If there are rows with the same rank, they all will be returned
order by rnk
```

Comment: I understand the answer, even though it is incorrect.  `dense_rank()` does not do what `with ties` does.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite tricky to replicate with window functions.  `fetch with ties` returns up to the *nth* row and then all rows with the same value.  So, one method is:

```
select s.*
from sales *
where s.unit_price <= (select s2.unit_price
                       from sales s2
                       order by unit_price 
                       limit 4, 1
                      );
```

This is not exact because it does not work if there are fewer than 5 rows.  An alternative using window functions makes this easier to fix:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             max(case when seqnum = 5 then unit_price end) over () as unit_price_5
      from (select s.*,
                   row_number() over (order by unit_price) as seqnum
            from s
           ) s
     ) s
where unit_price <= unit_price_5 or
      unit_price_5 is null;
```

Note that none of the built in window functions handle this situation.  For instance, if the prices are:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
```

Then `row_number()` would return only the first 5 `1`s.  `dense_rank()` and `rank()` would return all rows.